# Como posso fazer um laço para inserir dados em uma tabela no meu formulário para depois enviar para meu banco?

Tags: php, javascript, laravel

**//Parte do Formulário ao qual quero aplicar o laço**

```
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label>Curso</label>
            <input name="cursolivre" id="cursolivre" class="form-control" type="text" value="">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label>Segmento</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="segmento" id="segmento">
              <option value="Administrativo">Administrivo</option>
              <option value = "Tecnologico">Tecnológico</option>
              <option value="Tecnico">Técnico</option>
              <option Value="Livre">Livre</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-3">
            <label>Inicio</label>
            <input name="iniciol" id="iniciol" class="form-control" type="date" value="">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-3">
            <label>Termino</label>
            <input name="termino" id="termino" class="form-control" type="date" value="">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-2">
            <label>Carga Horário</label>
            <input name="cargahorario" id="cargahorario" class="form-control" type="number" value="">
          </div>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-adicionar-curso-livre" onclick="inserirTabela()" type="button"><span></span><img src="{{ asset('imagens/plus.png')}}" width="20px" alt="">  <strong>Nova Atividade</strong></button>
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-12">
            <table class="table table-striped">
              <thead class="table-light">
                <tr>
                  <th scope="col">Curso</th>
                  <th scope="col">Segmento</th>
                  <th scope="col">Inicio</th>
                  <th scope="col">Termino</th>
                  <th scope="col">Carga Horário</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <th id="dado1"></th>
                  <th id="dado2"></th>
                  <th id="dado3"></th>
                  <th id="dado4"></th>
                  <th id="dado5"></th>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
```

**//Código de inserção**

```
function inserirTabela(){
  var curso = document.form1.cursolivre.value;
  var segmento = document.form1.segmento.value;
  var inicio = document.form1.iniciol.value;
  var termino = document.form1.termino.value;
  var cargahorario = document.form1.cargahorario.value;

  document.getElementById("dado1").innerHTML = curso;
  document.getElementById("dado2").innerHTML = segmento;
  document.getElementById("dado3").innerHTML = inicio;
  document.getElementById("dado4").innerHTML = termino;
  document.getElementById("dado5").innerHTML = cargahorario;
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando eu clicar em nova atividade, preciso inserir ela em uma nova linha abaixo da primeira atividade, guardar em um array para poder enviar para meu banco.

Comment: O ideal seria você criar um objeto Javascript, e a cada post você iria incluindo esse objeto de um novo registro em um array. No procedimento de salvar no banco de dados. Ai você teria varias abordagens, pode mandar o array para o server, para que o server persista, ou criar uma função que percorra o array, indo ao server para cada registro. Se quiser alguma dessas abordagens, posso criar uma resposta com o código Js para você.

Comment: Eu aceito sim, preciso de um norte!

Answer (score 0):

Allan, basicamente o que você precisa é trabalhar com um objeto javascript.
Chamarei esse objeto de atividade.

**Classe model**

```
function atividade() {
    this.curso: undefined,
    this.segmento: undefined,
    this.inicio: undefined,
    this.termino: undefined,
    this.cargahorario: undefined  
}
```

Eu inicializo as propriedades do objeto com *undefined*, por uma preferencia minha, mas você pode iniciar com *null*, *``*, da forma que você entender que lhe é mais conveniente de acordo com o escopo de seu projeto.

**Evento clique do botão nova atividade**

Bem, agora que temos o objeto, no evento de clique do botão nova atividade, você deve mapear o objeto atividade com os valores do formulário.

```
var novaAtividade = new atividade();

novaAtividade.curso = document.form1.cursolivre.value;
novaAtividade.segmento = document.form1.segmento.value;
novaAtividade.inicio = document.form1.iniciol.value;
novaAtividade.termino = document.form1.termino.value;
novaAtividade.cargahorario = document.form1.cargahorario.value;

atividades.push(novaAividade);
```

A variável `atividades`, é um array que deve ser criado em um escopo global do arquivo que controla a tela com o seu formulário, sua declaração deve ser feito da seguinte forma:

```
var atividades = [];
```

`[]` diz que a variável atividade recebera um array vazio, desta forma o método `push()` se torna possível de ser executado.

`push()` fará a inclusão do objeto `novaAtividade` no final do array.

Desta forma o usuário pode incluir quantias atividades quiser. Para esta resposta vou assumir a abordagem de percorrer o array `atividades`, e ir ao server para cada registro. Para a abordagem de persistir o array, já tem que ser no server, mas imagino que a ideia em `php,` seja a mesma que farei com `JS`.

**Persistir**

Como nao conheço, a sua função, irei apenas descrever *idaAoServer(atividade)*, para identificar o momento de persistir a entidade.

Basicamente, no botão que terá o evento de salvar os dados digitados pelo usuário, você deve incluir o seguinte bloco:

```
for (atividade in atividades){
    idaAoServer(atividade);
}
```

**Referencias**

[Objetos com construtor em javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor)

[Método push](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp)

[for in objects javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)

Comment: primeiramente muito obrigado por está me ajudando, não abusando como irei fazer para os dados adicionados apareçam embaixo na tabela? A imagem que eu mandei mostra parte do formulário que está dividido em categorias, essa adição é para o usuário visualizar, o envio dos dados para o banco vai ser só no final. Recapitulando quero somente adicionar mais de uma atividade na tabela abaixo, e quando o usuário terminar os outros campos do formulário vai enviar tudo.

Comment: ok, você tem que usar o php ou o javascript, para fazer um for no array ´atividades`. Ai você pode usar o javascript para isso, ou o php.

Comment: set iver alguma dificuldade, me avise, eu não tenho costume de usar javascript puro para isso, normalmente uso angularjs, é mais simples, rápido de usar.

Comment: Eu estou usando o laravel, php não seria melhor por questões de boas práticas?

Comment: Não sei te dizer em relação a boas práticas, pelo que sei do php ele resolve isso no server e te devolve o html modificado, eu prefiro o javascript pois ele ira resolver isso para você no browser do cliente, o que diminui idas ao server, e melhor o desempenho do seu app.

Comment: Bom então vou tentar fazer em javascript pela praticidade porém o exemplo que você me deu não sei como aplicar dentro do Framework(Laravel)

Comment: Me desculpe, eu não uso laravel, logo não sei como te ajudar nesta parte, acho que eu tinha de ter visto as suas tags, e não dado uma resposta. Eu uso javascript para tudo, e o meu server é totalmente desacoplado da apresentação. Então não sei como te auxiliar no php.

Comment: Pelo que li, você usa o laravel para fazer o que eu estou te orientando a fazer m javascript, ou seja, é uma resposta fora da sua realidade. Desculpe!

Comment: Tudo bem entendo,já que você é bom em javascript e tem conhecimentos com angular acho que pode me ajudar aqui:
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/298557/qual-a-sintaxe-correta-para-o-json-parse-nesse-caso-estou-usando-a-api-themov
Estou usando o Ionic que tem como base o Angular

Comment: Ah sim, vou olhar p vc.